# PHP contact form not working. Also the html5 validation isn't even working either

Tags: php, forms, html, validation

EDIT/UPDATE:

I moved my php code from my process.php file to the top of my contact.php file and it worked. So what am I missing from the process.php file that is not redirecting it back to the contact.php page?

This is my html in contact.php

```
<?php echo $message; ?>    
<form action="process.php" method="post" name="sign_up">
                                <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $_POST[first_name]; ?>" required/>
                                <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $_POST[last_name]; ?>" required/><br>
                            <label class="bill-address">Billing Address:<br>
                                <input type="text" name="address1" placeholder="Address 1" value="<?php echo $_POST[address1]; ?>" required/><br>
                                <input type="text" name="address2" placeholder="Address 2" value="<?php echo $_POST[address2]; ?>" /><br>
                                <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" value="<?php echo $_POST[city]; ?>" required/>
                            </label>
                            <?php  
                             $state_list = array('AL'=>"Alabama",  
                                        'AK'=>"Alaska",  
                                        'AZ'=>"Arizona",  
                                        'AR'=>"Arkansas",  
                                        'WV'=>"West Virginia",  
                                        'WI'=>"Wisconsin",  
                                        'WY'=>"Wyoming");
                            ?>
                            <select name="state">
                            <?php
                                while(list($k,$v) = each($state_list)) {
                                    $selected = '';
                                    if ($k == $_POST[state]) {
                                        $selected = ' selected="true"';
                                    }
                                echo "<option value=\"$k\"$selected>$v</option>\n";
                                } 
                            ?>
                            </select>
            <input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="Zip Code" value="<?php echo $_POST[zip]; ?>" required/>
            <br style="clear: left;" />
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="you@youremail.com" value="<?php echo $_POST[email]; ?>" required/>
            <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" value="<?php echo $_POST[phone]; ?>" required/>
    <h3>Choose your Package</h3>
        <select name="package">
            <option value="Free">Free!</option>
            <option value="Basic">Basic</option>
            <option value="Corporate">Corporate</option>
            <option value="Enterprise">Enterprise</option>
            <option value="Enterprise_20">Enterprise 20</option>
            <option value="Enterprise_50">Enterprise 50</option>
            <option value="Enterprise_100">Enterprise 100</option>
        </select>
    <h3>Add Media Package?</h3>
            <input type="radio" name="Yes" value="yes" />Yes
            <input type="radio" name="No" value="no" />No
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Send &raquo;</button>
    <?php echo $success_message; ?>
</form>
```

And this is my process.php

```
    //validate email
function is_valid_email($email) {

        $result = true;
        $pattern = '/^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)+$/i';
        if(!preg_match($pattern, $email)) {
            $result = false;
        }
        return $result;
    }

//when submit has been pressed, begin form validate
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $valid = true;
    $message = '';
    if ( $_POST['first_name'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please include your first name. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['last_name'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please include your last name. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['address1'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please include your billing address. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['city'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please enter a city. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['state'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please select a state. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['zip'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please include a zip code. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['phone'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please include your phone number. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( !is_valid_email($_POST['email']) ) {
        $message .= "A valid email is required. "; 
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['package'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "You forgot to select a service package. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }

    if ( $valid == true ) {
        $success_message = 'Brilliant I say! We will be in contact with you shortly.';

        //clear form when submission is successful
        unset($_POST);
    }
}
```

It is not working. Also the html5 validation isn't even working either. Is there something wrong with my form markup?

Comment: when i press submit without anything filled in in my form it still goes to run process.php but none of my validation errors show up.

Comment: You have too many lines of code for you to just say this is not working. What's not working? What's the error? Is there even an error? Localize your problem, and the quality of our answers and comments will improve as well.

Comment: please cut off your ``state_list`` array, avoid to post too much code here.

Comment: I dont get any erros when I press submit in my form.

When I press submit even when nothing in the form is filled in, I don't get any html5 required input errors, nor does my php form validation work.

Can anyone see if I'm missing something? I can't stare at it by myself any longer.

Comment: Uhh, because you never actually output `$message`, perhaps?

Comment: My not so fresh any longers eyes tell me that you first of all should learn how to properly indent code and how to separate HTML from PHP.

Comment: why are you appending other messages to ``$message`` ? and i dont see any ``echo $message`` in your code

Comment: does it go in my process.php page somewhere? I have my $message and $success_message in my contact.php markup.

Comment: sorry I do have echo $message above the <form> I just missed putting it in my post.

Comment: @hakre so that it will spit all the $messages out at one time whichever apply.

Comment: @MagdaleneB.: No to make your code more modular. That helps keeping errors out and if some happen, to locate the cause more quickly. ;)

Comment: any thoughts as to why the html5 form validation isn't running?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You need to change the `action` attribute of your form back to `contact.php`.  To clarify, this will reload `contact.php`, and display the `$message` and `$success_message` variables. `process.php` is now ignored entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on `submit`, your browser navigates to `process.php`. All of the code from `contact.php` is forgotten and a new page is generated.

There is no implied link between the two pages. The messages from `process.php` will not apppear on `contact.php`. Currently, `process.php` doesn't `echo` anything, so you're probably arriving at a blank page.

An alternate way to do this would be to merge the two pages like this:

```
<?php
    //validate email
function is_valid_email($email) {

        $result = true;
        $pattern = '/^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)+$/i';
        if(!preg_match($pattern, $email)) {
            $result = false;
        }
        return $result;
    }

//when submit has been pressed, begin form validate
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $valid = true;
    $message = '';
    if ( $_POST['first_name'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please include your first name. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['last_name'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please include your last name. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['address1'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please include your billing address. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['city'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please enter a city. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['state'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please select a state. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['zip'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please include a zip code. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['phone'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please include your phone number. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( !is_valid_email($_POST['email']) ) {
        $message .= "A valid email is required. "; 
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['package'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "You forgot to select a service package. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }

    if ( $valid == true ) {
        $success_message = 'Brilliant I say! We will be in contact with you shortly.';

        //clear form when submission is successful
                          //don't clear this, you need this to re-populate the page below
        //unset($_POST);
    }
}

?><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $message; ?>    
<form action="contact.php" method="post" name="sign_up">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $_POST[first_name]; ?>" required/>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $_POST[last_name]; ?>" required/><br>
    <label class="bill-address">Billing Address:<br>
        <input type="text" name="address1" placeholder="Address 1" value="<?php echo $_POST[address1]; ?>" required/><br>
        <input type="text" name="address2" placeholder="Address 2" value="<?php echo $_POST[address2]; ?>" /><br>
        <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" value="<?php echo $_POST[city]; ?>" required/>
    </label>
<?php  
$state_list = array('AL'=>"Alabama",  
                                        'AK'=>"Alaska",  
                                        'AZ'=>"Arizona",  
                                        'AR'=>"Arkansas",  
                                        'WV'=>"West Virginia",  
                                        'WI'=>"Wisconsin",  
                                        'WY'=>"Wyoming");
                            ?>
                            <select name="state">
                            <?php
                                while(list($k,$v) = each($state_list)) {
                                    $selected = '';
                                    if ($k == $_POST[state]) {
                                        $selected = ' selected="true"';
                                    }
                                echo "<option value=\"$k\"$selected>$v</option>\n";
                                } 
                            ?>
                            </select>
            <input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="Zip Code" value="<?php echo $_POST[zip]; ?>" required/>
            <br style="clear: left;" />
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="you@youremail.com" value="<?php echo $_POST[email]; ?>" required/>
            <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" value="<?php echo $_POST[phone]; ?>" required/>
    <h3>Choose your Package</h3>
        <select name="package">
            <option value="Free">Free!</option>
            <option value="Basic">Basic</option>
            <option value="Corporate">Corporate</option>
            <option value="Enterprise">Enterprise</option>
            <option value="Enterprise_20">Enterprise 20</option>
            <option value="Enterprise_50">Enterprise 50</option>
            <option value="Enterprise_100">Enterprise 100</option>
        </select>
    <h3>Add Media Package?</h3>
            <input type="radio" name="Yes" value="yes" />Yes
            <input type="radio" name="No" value="no" />No
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Send &raquo;</button>
    <?php echo $success_message; ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The `$message` and `$success_message` variables are now saved and they should display in the page markup below.

Comment: I just tested this and it works well like that. I'm just plain curious at this point though, because I fell like I've done it this way before and it worked. Oh well. :/

Answer (score 0):

```
     //validate email
     function is_valid_email($email) {

    $result = true;
    $pattern = '/^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)+$/i';
    if(!preg_match($pattern, $email)) {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

   //when submit has been pressed, begin form validate
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $valid = true;
  $message = '';
  if ( $_POST['first_name'] == "" ) {
    $message = "Please include your first name. ";
   echo $message;
    $valid = false; 
  }
if ( $_POST['last_name'] == "" ) {
    $message = "Please include your last name. ";
    echo $message;
    $valid = false; 
}
if ( $_POST['address1'] == "" ) {
    $message = "Please include your billing address. ";
    echo $message;
    $valid = false; 
  }
  if ( $_POST['city'] == "" ) {
    $message = "Please enter a city. ";
    echo $message;
    $valid = false; 
  }
  if ( $_POST['state'] == "" ) {
    $message = "Please select a state. ";
  echo $message;
    $valid = false; 
}
if ( $_POST['zip'] == "" ) {
    $message = "Please include a zip code. ";
   echo $message;
    $valid = false; 
}
if ( $_POST['phone'] == "" ) {
    $message = "Please include your phone number. ";<
    echo $message;
    $valid = false; 
}
if ( !is_valid_email($_POST['email']) ) {
    $message = "A valid email is required. ";
    echo $message; 
    $valid = false; 
}
if ( $_POST['package'] == "" ) {
    $message = "You forgot to select a service package. ";
    echo $message;
    $valid = false; 
}

if ( $valid == true ) {
    $success_message = 'Brilliant I say! We will be in contact with you shortly.';
    echo $success_message;

    //clear form when submission is successful
    unset($_POST);
}
```

}

i added `echo $message` for echoing during validation and `.=` was i think wrong way, otherwise you would have a message that contains all error messages..

Comment: I added this, but all it does is just sit at the process.php page still, blank.

Comment: dont pring all the message as one string, it is confusing, user doesnot know where the typo was

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this after the `unset( $_POST )` line:

```
header('Location: contact.php');
```

That should take you back to the `contact.php` page.

EDIT:

However, in order for your code completely to work the way you want it, here what I would do.

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    if (isset ($_SESSION['message'])) {
        echo $_SESSION['message'];
        session_destroy();
    }
?>    
<form action="process.php" method="post" name="sign_up">
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $_POST[first_name]; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $_POST[last_name]; ?>" /><br>
<label class="bill-address">Billing Address:<br>
<input type="text" name="address1" placeholder="Address 1" value="<?php echo $_POST[address1]; ?>" /><br>
<input type="text" name="address2" placeholder="Address 2" value="<?php echo $_POST[address2]; ?>" /><br>
<input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" value="<?php echo $_POST[city]; ?>" />
    </label>
<?php  
   $state_list = array('AL'=>"Alabama",  
    'AK'=>"Alaska",  
    'AZ'=>"Arizona",  
    'AR'=>"Arkansas",  
    'WV'=>"West Virginia",  
    'WI'=>"Wisconsin",  
    'WY'=>"Wyoming");
?>
     <select name="state">
 <?php
    while(list($k,$v) = each($state_list)) {
    $selected = '';
    if ($k == $_POST[state]) {
   $selected = ' selected="true"';
}
 echo "<option value=\"$k\"$selected>$v</option>\n";
} 
?>
</select>
<input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="Zip Code" value="<?php echo $_POST[zip]; ?>" />
<br style="clear: left;" />
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="you@youremail.com" value="<?php echo $_POST[email]; ?>" />
<input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" value="<?php echo $_POST[phone]; ?>" />
<h3>Choose your Package</h3>
<select name="package">
           <option value="Free">Free!</option>
            <option value="Basic">Basic</option>
            <option value="Corporate">Corporate</option>
            <option value="Enterprise">Enterprise</option>
            <option value="Enterprise_20">Enterprise 20</option>
            <option value="Enterprise_50">Enterprise 50</option>
            <option value="Enterprise_100">Enterprise 100</option>
</select>
    <h3>Add Media Package?</h3>
            <input type="radio" name="Yes" value="yes" />Yes
            <input type="radio" name="No" value="no" />No
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Send &raquo;</button>
<?php 
    //session already started on line 2

    if (isset( $_SESSION['success'] )) {
        echo $_SESSION['success'];
        session_destroy();
    }
?>

</form>
```

That's for `contact.php`, and

```
<?php

//when submit has been pressed, begin form validate else return to contact.php
  if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] == "POST" ) {
    session_start();


    //validate email
function is_valid_email($email) {

        $result = true;
        $pattern = '/^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)+$/i';
        if(!preg_match($pattern, $email)) {
            $result = false;
        }
        return $result;
    }


    $valid = true;
    $message = '';
    if ( $_POST['first_name'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please include your first name. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['last_name'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please include your last name. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['address1'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please include your billing address. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['city'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please enter a city. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['state'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please select a state. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['zip'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please include a zip code. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['phone'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "Please include your phone number. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( !is_valid_email($_POST['email']) ) {
        $message .= "A valid email is required. "; 
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['package'] == "" ) {
        $message .= "You forgot to select a service package. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }

    if ( $valid == true ) {
        $success_message = 'Brilliant I say! We will be in contact with you shortly.';

        //clear form when submission is successful
        unset($_POST);
        $_SESSION['success']=$success_message;
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
    }
    header('Location: contact.php');
} // end of if ( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] == "POST" )
else header('Location: contact.php');

?>
```

`process.php`

The following control I think was creating the biggest confusion in your code:

```
//when submit has been pressed, begin form validate
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

as soon as I replaced it, everything started to work better.